# Stack Overflow in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I am a newbie to java and jboss and at one of my classes asked me to go find out what the following means in a stack trace? Could any of you pros please help me out?

org.jboss.Main$1.run

Comment: What part is confusing? Do you feel like you know what a stack trace is? Do you understand what org.jboss means? What about Main? See if you can break down those parts.

Comment: I have a idea of what org.jboss, Main means , just was unsure about what "$1" signifies?

Answer (score 3):

org.jboss.Main$1 is a compiler-generated class name for the first anonymous inner class in the class org.jboss.Main. This is the run method on that inner class being called.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the point is inside the `run` method of an anonymous class (thus the `$1`) inside the class `Main` of e package `org.jboss`.